# What's the elegant way waiting for data to load

Tags: objective-c

While networking requests need time to load, I set up a while loop to wait for the data. Before the networking request is done, the variable myData is nil. Code is like this:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            while (![[DataStore sharedInstance]myData]) {
                NSLog(@"still wating...");
            }
            _dataArray = [[DataStore sharedInstance]myData];
            [_tableView reloadData];
        });
```

Thus I set up a queue infinitely waiting for data loading. While it's done, the queue could finally go on to next order: reload tableView.

Is it good code keeping a queue do something like this? Would it be a huge waste on cpu resource?

Comment: What about a block, or maybe a notification? Because it's seems you're blocking the UI...

Comment: The most elegant way is **not** to wait for data but rather use a completion block. Polling is very expensive.